# I need help to fix a blank emails from my form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm getting everyday in around the same hour 6 blank emails from my contact form, if I fill the form in the website all the info go through and I'm getting the email with the details, I have a validation for my form but still getting the blank emails. What do I need to do?

At the beginning I was getting an error for some lines in my php but it's already fixed but I'm still getting the blank emails.

This is My PHP code:

```
$fname = $lname = $email = $tel = $address = $project = $message = '';

if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
}

if (isset($_POST['lname'])) {
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}

if (isset($_POST['tel'])) {
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
}

if (isset($_POST['address'])) {
    $address = $_POST['address'];
}

if (isset($_POST['project'])) {
    $project = $_POST['project'];
}

if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
}

    $to = '...';
    $email_subject = "$fname $lname Contact You from ... :";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.<br/>"."Here are the details:<br/><br/> Name: $fname $lname<br/> Email: $email<br/> Phone: $tel<br/> Address: $address<br/> Project: $project<br/> Message:\n$message";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ...' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ...' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)) {
            echo "OK";
        }
```

This Is my HTML code:

```
                <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                            <label for="fname">First Name*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" id="fname" data-rule="minlen:3" data-msg="*Please Enter at Least 3 Chars" />
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                            <label for="lname">Last Name*</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" id="lname" data-rule="minlen:3" data-msg="*Please Enter at Least 3 Chars" />
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                            <label for="tel">Phone Number*</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="tel" id="tel" data-rule="minlen:10" data-msg="*Please Enter a Valid Phone Number" />
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email Address*</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" data-rule="email" data-msg="*Please Enter a Valid Email Address" />
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                            <label for="address">Location (Address)</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" />
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                            <label for="project">Select Project / Service</label>
                            <select type="text" class="form-control" name="project" id="project">
                                <option selected value="">Select Project</option>
                                <option value="Emergency HVAC Service">Emergency HVAC Service</option>
                                <option value="Air Conditioner Installation">Air Conditioner Installation</option>
                                <option value="Air Conditioner Repair">Air Conditioner Repair</option>
                                <option value="Air Conditioner Replacement">Air Conditioner Replacement</option>
                                <option value="Duct Repair">Duct Repair</option>
                                <option value="Duct Replacement">Duct Replacement</option>
                                <option value="Furnace Repair">Furnace Repair</option>
                                <option value="HVAC Maintenance">HVAC Maintenance</option>
                                <option value="Air Duct Cleaning">Air Duct Cleaning</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                            <div class="validation"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hide-button" class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1 text-center">
                            <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
                            <div id="errormessage">Sorry! Something went wrong. Try again.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Javascript Validation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  //Contact
  $('form.contactForm').submit(function() {
    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;

    f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'email':
            if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'checked':
            if (!i.attr('checked')) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'regexp':
            exp = new RegExp(exp);
            if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') !== undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    f.children('textarea').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    if (ferror) return false;
    else var str = $(this).serialize();
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    if( ! action ) {
      action = 'mail/mailer.php';
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: action,
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        // alert(msg);
        if (msg == 'OK') {
          $('#hide-button').addClass("hide");
          $("#sendmessage").addClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").removeClass("show");
          $('.contactForm').find("input, textarea").val("");
        } else {
          $('#hide-button').removeClass("hide");
          $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
        }

      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Tell me if I need to add my jQuery. 
I'm very familiar with html and css but not that much with PHP and Javascript.

Comment: You said you have validator on the form but I don't see code for that, can you post it here? is it PHP or Javascript? As a rule of thumb, you should have both front end (javascript/html5) and backend validator (PHP)

Comment: Its a javascript validation and I just add it to my question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have client-side validation in the form of some JavaScript/jQuery stuff, but the fact is that **you can't trust the client**. Client-side validation is there to help the user, but **must not be relied on by the server**.

Someone can craft a POST request to your form processing PHP script without using a browser at all, so they can send any old data they like. Probably what you're seeing is emails from some crawler bot or similar doing exactly this.

So, you need to add some similar validation logic to your PHP code (which is obviously on the server side, and therefore much more trustworthy than code on the client side). For example, to check the `lname` field isn't blank, you could do:

```
if (empty($lname)) {
    showErrorPage('Please enter a last name!');
    exit; // To halt processing.
}
```

Comment: I used this template for 2 different website and in one of them I was getting the blank too but after I fixed the error that I had at the beginning in one of them its just stopped

Comment: That proves that it's just a coincidence then. Your current code doesn't prevent someone sending a `POST` request to your PHP script (by using `curl`, for example) with blank or missing data. Read through your PHP code and think about what would happen if `$_POST` was an empty array (i.e. `$_POST = [];`).